# Can't access my smartphone through neither adb/fastboot or GUI

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, mtp

So I was about to format my phone and install a lineage ROM (as I already did a thousand times before and always worked) but my phone now ended in a very strange situation. First I booted TRWP recovery mode and ran a wipe, then rebooted back to recovery and plugged my phone in the pc to transfer de rom zip. After pluging it my pc, KDE desktop shows that a "moto g is connected (...)" and give me the options to browse its folders through the GUI but by clicking on it fails with the message:

> "The process for the mtp protocol died unexpectedly".

So I ignore it and decided to transfer the zip through `adb push` but `adb devices` finds no attached device. The same happens for `fastboot devices`. I've made a little search and found that the mount folders for mtp can be located in either `/run/user/$USER/gvfs/` or `/var/run/user/$UID/gvfs` but both of these are empty. So I'm now at a stalemate (i think this is the right english word). I don't know how to proceed. All I want to do is transfer the files to reinstall my system (rom.zip, opengapps.zip and magisk.zip). Any ideia what is happening, and, how to solve it (if possible)?

Comment: Does the device have an SD Card slot?

Comment: also no, or else I'd have already put my zip files there :)

Comment: hum well, next thing I would try would be flashing a stock image using RSD Lite, then restart the custom ROM installation processes. Which model is that phone?

Comment: Also, did you try manually booting in bootloader with key combo? ADB won't show up if MTP is broken (in recovery) IMO.

Comment: yes I booted into bootloader with key combo (down volume + power button), it is now the only way I can get into rec mode. but inside bootloader I can't see my phone through `fastboot devices`, the luck I had is that trwp rec is already installed

Comment: Fine then, flash it with stock firmeware. You should get back ADB  and be able to flash a custom ROM.

Comment: how? you mean doing a factory reset?

Comment: No, a complete firmware installation.

Comment: but wouldn't this require the fastboot command to detect my phone to run the flash command?

Comment: Of course fastboot is required. I heard you are able to boot in the bootloader right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83200/discussion-between-fabiotk-and-esqmo).

Comment: Oh, missed the part your device isn't getting detected even in bootloader mode

Answer (score 1):

So after a talk and help from user [esQmo_](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/186278/esqmo) in the chat, the only possible explanation would be my local install of android tools to be broken. I've tested by installing adb and fastboot in another machine and there it was possible to the device to be accessed (it was visible throught all adb, fastboot mtp didn't failed)

Comment: Glad I helped :D